# Split an array of objects into smaller arrays based on the number of each object's subitems

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to accomplish something similar to the _.chunk() function in lodash.  The chunk function breaks an array into equal parts, based on the quantity of objects in the original array.

However, I want to break a Javascript array into smaller arrays based on the quantity of the object's subitems. So the new arrays can have a varying number of elements, but the quantity of subitems in each new array must total 3(except for the last array if there is a remainder).

For example, I want to use Javascript to convert this array:

```
[ {name:'John', numberOfPets: 5, 
pets:['petOne', 'petTwo', 'petThree', 'petFour', 'petFive']}, 
{ name:'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5,
pets: ['petSix', 'petSeven', 'petEight', 'petNine', 'petTen']}]
```

Into these arrays:

```
[{name: 'John', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petOne', 'petTwo', 'petThree']}],

[{name: 'John', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petFour', 'petFive']},
{name: 'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petSix']}],

[{name: 'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petSeven', 'petEight', 
'petNine']}],

[{name: 'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petTen']}]
```

You will notice the new arrays each have 3 pets, except for the last array which just has 1 remainder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is pets? Array or object? It cant be both...

Comment: Yeah the `pets` property of each object is invalid as posted above.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  Pets is an array, I've updated the syntax.  I will try out your code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is on the right track to what BeccaGirl is looking for.  It may need some re-factoring.

```js
var chunks = function(array, size) {
  var results = [];
  while (array.length) {
    results.push(array.splice(0, size));
  }
  return results;
};

var chunkSize = 3, newArray = [], chunkPets = [];
var oldArray = [ {name:'John', numberOfPets: 5, 
pets:['petOne', 'petTwo', 'petThree', 'petFour', 'petFive']}, 
{ name:'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5,
pets: ['petSix', 'petSeven', 'petEight', 'petNine', 'petTen']}];
var newArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++){
  chunkPets = chunks(oldArray[i].pets, chunkSize);
  for(var j=0; j<chunkPets.length; j++)
  {
    if(chunkPets[j].length === chunkSize || i+1 === oldArray.length)
    {
   newArray.push([{name: oldArray[i].name, numberOfPets: oldArray[i].numberOfPets, pets: chunkPets[j]}]);
    }
    else{
       var tempArray = [];
       tempArray.push({name: oldArray[i].name, numberOfPets: oldArray[i].numberOfPets, pets: chunkPets[j]});
       
       if(oldArray.length > i+1){
       tempArray.push({name: oldArray[i+1].name, numberOfPets: oldArray[i+1].numberOfPets, pets: oldArray[i+1].pets.splice(0,chunkSize - chunkPets[j].length)});
       
       oldArray[i+1].pets = oldArray[i+1].pets.splice(chunkSize -chunkPets[j].length-1,oldArray[i+1].pets.length);
       newArray.push(tempArray);
       }
    }
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 const result = [], size = 3;

 for(const {name, pets} of owners)
   for(let chunk = 0; chunk < pets.length; chunk += size)
       result.push({name, pets: pets.slice(chunk, chunk + size)});
```

Just chunk that for every person. I assume that your array is called `owners` (thought it would fit) and that `owner.pets` is an array (cause that would make sense too). Also note that your `numberOfPets` is unneccessary, as you can use `pets.length`;)

Comment: Each object has the original `numberOfPets`, so it is necessary in the output chunked array, although it can be derived from the length of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `pets` in each input object is actually an array (which means it should be delimited by `[`...`]`, not `{`...`}`), you can achieve the desired results with something like this:

```
const input = [{
        name: 'John',
        numberOfPets: 5,
        pets: [
            'petOne',
            'petTwo',
            'petThree',
            'petFour',
            'petFive'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Andrew',
        numberOfPets: 5,
        pets: [
            'petSix',
            'petSeven',
            'petEight',
            'petNine',
            'petTen'
        ]
    }
]

const chunked = input.reduce(␣
  function(output, item) {
     const master = {...item}
     while (master.pets.length > 0) {
        const copy = {...master}
        copy.pets = master.pets.slice(0,3)
        master.pets = master.pets.slice(3)
        output.push(copy)
    }
    return output
 }, [])

console.log(chunked)
```

That results in `chunked` being this:

```
[ { name: 'John',
    numberOfPets: 5,
    pets: [ 'petOne', 'petTwo', 'petThree' ] },
  { name: 'John', numberOfPets: 5, pets: [ 'petFour', 'petFive' ] },
  { name: 'Andrew',
    numberOfPets: 5,
    pets: [ 'petSix', 'petSeven', 'petEight' ] },
  { name: 'Andrew',
    numberOfPets: 5,
    pets: [ 'petNine', 'petTen' ] } ]
```

Comment: I don't think the output is quite right yet, as I would need it to return an array of arrays, and each array should ultimately have 3 pets.  So since there are 10 pets total, the arrays would have 3 pets, 3 pets, 3 pets and the last array would have 1 pet.

Comment: How are you going to combine two of John's pets and one of Andrew's into a single object?

Comment: It would be an array that contains 2 objects, one of John's pets and one of Andrew's pets:                                                                                                       
    [{name: 'John', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petFour', 'petFive']},
    {name: 'Andrew', numberOfPets: 5, pets: ['petSix]}]